# Debug only one thread with ida-gdb server

Tags: ida, gdb, embedded, process, thread

If I want to debug process in embedded that running linux , I can run gdb-server in embedded and attach to process with Ida.

The problem is if this process has 1 thread that can't stop over than x seconds (for example this thread feed the watchdog).

How can I attach to debug all threads in the process instead the thread that feed the watchdog(I know the thread id) . Or maybe debug only 1 thread in the process that interesting me.

When I attach to process and debug all thread are stopped.